# AngularJS + NG-Grid pass row.column.field into ng-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

How does one pass `{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}` into `ng-click`?  What happens is the id does not get propagated back, but the grid render correctly with the id.

code:

```
var app = angular.module('testing',['ngGrid']);
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider)  
{  
       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);    

app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope)  
{  
      $scope.details = []; //whatever dummy data  
      $scope.loadById = function(id)  
      {  
            $window.location.href= 'newPage/?id='+id;
      };  

      $scope.gridOptions =  
      {  
           data: 'details',  
           columnDefs:[{field:'id',DisplayName:'id',  
                 cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-click="loadById({{row.getProperty(col.field)}})">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>'  
              }]
      };    
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can **just pass row in ng-click**, instead of only the value outputted by the double brackets expression.

Your cellTemplate becomes this

```
cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-click="loadById(row)">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>'
```

Your function becomes this

```
$scope.loadById = function(row) {  
   window.console && console.log(row.entity);
   $window.location.href= 'newPage/?id='+ row.entity.id;
};
```